# Kernel of the representation of the mapping class group to $Aut(F_n)$

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory

Let $S_{g,1}$ be a orientable compact surface of genus $g$ with one boundary component and $\Gamma_{g,1}$ the mapping class group. 
By $F_n$ I denote the free group on $n$ generators.

One obtains a representation $\rho: \Gamma_{g,1} \rightarrow Aut(F_{2g})$.

What is the kernel of $\rho$?

Comment: To be clear, you are placing a base point on the boundary of $S_{g,1}$.  Otherwise, you only get a representation into $\mathrm{Out}(F)$.

Comment: @HW and lsw: Could you clarify what is $\rho$ and why it depends on where the basepoint is (as long as it is fixed)?  

Comment: @HW: Thank you for making this precise.
@Mark Sapir: You have to consider the induced action on the fundamental group of $S_{g,1}$. By fixing a base-point there is no $Inn(\pi_1)$-action.

Comment: @Isw: Why is the kernel non-trivial?

Comment: @Mark Sapir: I don't know. Why is it trivial?


Comment: @Isw: I thought that the non-triviality is at least known,  that is why I asked (otherwise why don't you include this subquestion in your question?). An element in the kernel should take every curve based at the boundary point to a homotopic curve. Right? I would like to see a non-trivial mapping class which does it. For example a pseudo-Anosov element cannot belong to the kernel since the images of any simple closed curve under powers of a pseudo-Anosov span the whole surface. There are people on MO who know this much better than I, so they will probably answer.  

Comment: @Isw - You also need to take the correct definition of the mapping class group, namely using homeomorphisms that fix the basepoint (equivalently, fix the boundary pointwise), up to isotopy. This done, the homomorphism $\rho$ is well-defined and the kernel is trivial, as Ian writes below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The representation is faithful, since a mapping class is determined by its action on the fundamental group of the surface. A surface is a $K(\pi,1)$, so given any element $Aut(S_{g,1})$, one obtains a (pointed) map $\varphi:S_{g,1}\to S_{g,1}$ which is unique up to homotopy. Now one needs to know that two homotopic homeomorphisms of a surface are isotopic, which is classic (at least one may find this in a [paper of Waldhausen](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=224099)). In fact, one may identify the image in $Aut(F_{2g})$ as the subgroup preserving the peripheral element. 
Also, note that everything should be fixing a basepoint in the boundary, as in HW's comment.