# What is known about the map $\text{Mod}_g^1 \rightarrow \text{Aut}(F_{2g})$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory, mapping-class-groups, free-groups

**Follow up question, edited in on 12/20 below:**

Letting $\text{Mod}_g^1$ be the mapping class group of a surface with one boundary component (and basepoint on the boundary) and identify its fundamental group with $F_{2g}$. The action of $\text{Mod}_g^1$ on $F_{2g}$ gives a map $$\text{Mod}_g^1 \rightarrow \text{Aut}(F_{2g})$$

What is known about this map? I know it is injective (see [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87022/kernel-of-the-representation-of-the-mapping-class-group-to-autf-n)) and can determine the action of specific mapping classes by drawing how they act on a generating set for the fundamental group.

- Are there any sources that make this map explicit?
- Is its image known? It isn't surjective: since $\text{Mod}_g^1$ must fix the boundary (given by the surface relation) pointwise, we must hit automorphisms that act trivially on the surface relation
- What about restrictions to the Torelli group (with image $IA_n$)?

**12/19 EDIT:** I'm calculating the image of a mapping class (specifically, the classic example of a bounding pair map around the  second hole in the genus 3 surface) in $\text{Aut}(F_{2g})$, and checking that it stabilizes the surface relation. I found that it sends $[a_1,b_1][a_2,b_2][a_3,b_3]$ to $[a_1,b_1][a_3,b_3][a_2,b_2]$. Have I done something wrong?

If it were true that
$$[a_1,b_1][a_2,b_2][a_3,b_3] = 1 \iff [a_1,b_1][a_3,b_3][a_2,b_2] =1,$$
then I'd think this is ok. But unless I'm missing something stupid, I don't think this is the case.

**12/20 EDIT:** New question in comments, trying to find my error. thank you!

Comment: Its image is the stabiliser of the surface relation $\prod_i[a_i,b_i]$. This is mentioned in a 1975 paper of McCool (McCool, James
Some finitely presented subgroups of the automorphism group of a free group.
J. Algebra 35 (1975)), who appears to attribute it to Harvey and Maclachlan.

Comment: @HJRW: my understanding is Dehn gave the first proof of this.  You can find a translation of this work in "Papers on group theory and topology" by John Stillwell (1987).  But there's versions going back to Baer (1928), Nielson (1927) and Seifert (1937).  The map is known  to be injective, as well.

Comment: @RyanBudney: that doesn’t surprise me one bit. It certainly feels like something that Dehn  knew. My copy of Stillwell is in my office, so I don’t have it to hand.

Comment: @RyanBudney: I just checked Harvey--Maclachlan, and they seem to think that Nielsen only handled the closed case. Of course, Lickorish famously rediscovered Dehn's theorem that the mapping class group is generated by twists, so it wouldn't be the first time that a pre-war German theorem about mapping class groups was rediscovered in the post-war UK.

Comment: Regarding the question about the restriction to the Torelli group, this is pretty much tautological given Dehn's perspective, as you can compute the action on homology from the automorphism of the fundamental group.  Are your questions answered in the comments, Chase?

Comment: Questions answered - thank you everyone!

Comment: I have a follow up question, which I edited in just now

Comment: @Chase: You are definitely doing something wrong.  It should be geometrically obvious that all mapping classes fix the boundary curve since they’re literally required to fix the boundary pointwise.  If I had to guess, you’re probably using the wrong convention for commutators and your expression for the boundary curve is not the boundary curve.  Carefully draw it and make sure.

Comment: Now I have $a_1 \rightarrow b_2 a_1 b_2^{-1}$ and $b_1 \rightarrow b_2 b_1 b_2^{-1}$ and $a_2 \rightarrow [a_1, b_1]a_2$, and all else fixed. This sends $[a_1,b_1][a_2,b_2][a_3,b_3]$ to $b_2[a_1,b_1]b_2^{-1}[[a_1,b_1]a_2,b_2][a_3,b_3]$, which isn't good. Is anything obviously wrong here so far?

Comment: @Chase: This is really impossible for someone else to check.  If you draw the picture of your mapping class, it should literally fix the boundary component pointwise, and in particular should fix the loop around the boundary component.